# bounded variation and quasicontiuity

Tags: real-analysis

We say $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is quasicontinuous if the right and left hand limits of $f(x)$ exist at each $x \in [a,b]$ (of course, only the right hand limit at $x=a$ and left hand limit at $x=b$).

Corollory 13.8 in Carothers' *Real Analysis* states that if $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is of bounded variation then it is quasicontinuous (stated without proof). This is stated right after it was proven that $f$ is of bounded variation iff $f$ is the difference of two increasing functions.

So, why must $f$ be quasicontinuous if it is of bounded variaton?

Thanks.

Comment: Because monotone functions are quasicontinuous, and sums of quasicontinuous functions are again quasicontinuous.

Comment: Right, I figured that right after posting the question, it just seems that the result about monotone functions being quasicontinuous is too obscure for the author to not mention.

Comment: If $f$ is not quasicontinuous, then $f$ has [essential discontinuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuity_(mathematics)) so $f$ is not BV.